# How to fix html resource relative path 404?

Tags: html, koa

I have directory like this:

```
/xyz/index.html
/xyz/js/index.js
/xyz/css/index.css
```

Now in `index.html` I import `js` and `css` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

when I access `index.html` like this:

```
http://localhost/xyz/index.html
```

it works fine, but if I access it like this:

```
http://localhost/xyz
```

it reports `404`.
Do I have any choice to fix this **if I do not change to absolute path**?

---

Edit:
My server side is using `Koa` serve static files.

```
import * as serve from "koa-static";
import { resolve } from "path";
app.use(serve(resolve(__dirname, "public"))
```

Comment: @Teemu I have edit my question

Comment: OK, I tagged this also with Koa, someone knowing Koa can now find the question.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm just hostic my files with vercel.

Did you ever find a solution that did not involve changing to absolute path?

Comment: It might work if you add `<base href="/xyz/">` in the head of your `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution to your problem to fix the relative path to the resources, `index.html` should be updated to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="xyz/css/index.css">
<script src="xyz/js/index.js"></script>
```